# I am trying to show a collection grid using flexbox but i am not able to get the layout right

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

I am trying to achieve following responsive layout using flexbox as show in below image..

[image]

i tried few thing but is not getting the desired result.

Each item in this design has a image and top of that i need to show blog Title, date & category but i am not able to get the layout right

Currently i am doing same without flexbox but its lot of css and other tags, i though i could change same with less code using flex.

I have looked at lot of example but i am not able to find 1 example similar to my layout

current page is using bootstrap v3.3.6 which i cant change as it can impact other parts of the website

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.flex-container > div {
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
  color: white;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 75px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
.flex1 {
 flex: 100%;
  max-height:372px;
}
.flex2 {
   flex:25%;
  max-height:372px;
}
.flex3 {
   flex:25%;
  max-height:372px;
}
.flex4 {
   flex:25%;
  max-height:372px;
}
.flex5 {
   flex:25%;
  max-height:372px;
}
.flex-container > div  > span {
  position:absolute;
  z-index:1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row row-margin">
    <div class="flex-container">
      <div class="flex1">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/645x424/753075/fff.jpg&text=Image" class="img-responsive">
        <span>1</span>
      </div>
      <div class="flex2">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/480x360/3b063b/fff.jpg&text=Image" class="img-responsive">
        <span>2</span>
      </div>
      <div class="flex3">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/645x424/3b063b/fff.jpg&text=Image" class="img-responsive">
        <span>3</span>
      </div>
      <div class="flex4">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/480x360/3b063b/fff.jpg&text=Image" class="img-responsive">
        <span>4</span>
      </div>
      <div class="flex5">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/480x360/3b063b/fff.jpg&text=Image" class="img-responsive">
        <span>5</span>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to do it using grid and this is responsive without writing any extra media queries

basic working code example https://codepen.io/KGuide/pen/xxPWxKj

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="column1 columnX grid-col" style="background-color:#f00;">
 <img src="https://dummyimage.com/645x424/753075/fff.jpg&text=Image" class="img-responsive">
    <h2>Column 1</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
</div>

<div class=" column2 column grid-col" style="background-color:#f00;">
<div class="row margin-0">
  <div class="column grid-col" style="background-color:#aaa;">
   <img src="https://dummyimage.com/645x424/753075/fff.jpg&text=Image" class="img-responsive">
    <h2>Column 2</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column grid-col" style="background-color:#bbb;">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/645x424/753075/fff.jpg&text=Image" class="img-responsive">
    <h2>Column 3</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row margin-0">
  <div class="column grid-col" style="background-color:#ccc;">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/645x424/753075/fff.jpg&text=Image" class="img-responsive">
    <h2>Column 4</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column grid-col" style="background-color:#ddd;">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/645x424/753075/fff.jpg&text=Image" class="img-responsive">
    <h2>Column 5</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
</div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Create two equal columns that floats next to each other */
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 1px;
  margin:0;
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
/* Style the buttons */
.btn {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.btn:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
.btn.active {
  background-color: #666;
  color: white;
}
.column1{float: left; width:50%; padding:0; margin:0;}
.column2{float: left; width:50%; padding:0; margin:0;}
.grid-col {position:relative;}
.grid-col > img {z-index:9;}
.grid-col > h2,p {position:absolute; z-index:10;top:30px;left:25px;  }
.margin-0{margin:0px;}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you use grid, there are many ways to achieve this but most definitely flex is not the best way to deal with a grid like this if you care about media query. Nevertheless, one way is to use positions and flex. But its a trade off.

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 1px;
}

.item {
    height: 4rem;
    width: 4rem;
    background-color: antiquewhite;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.item-1 {
    height: 8rem;
    width: 8rem;
}

.item-2,
.item-3 {
    margin-top: -4rem;
}

.row {
    display: flex;
    gap: 1px;
}

.item-4 {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 1px;
}

.item-5 {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 1px;
    margin-left: 4.1rem;
}
```

```html
  <div class="container">
    <div class="item item-1">1</div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="item item-2">2</div>
      <div class="item item-3">3</div>
      <div class="item item-4">4</div>
      <div class="item item-5">6</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I have also realised that you can wrap the 2 items 2 and 4 into a single div and set its flex-direction to column, do the same for 3 and 6 items.

Comment: After reading articles, i am also looking for grid option, looking at your example you are using fixed with while i want it responsive.

Comment: You can use widths as percentages, that way, they will also be responsive. Nevertheless, it is much easier with grid.

Here is a link to learn.
https://flexboxfroggy.com/

Here for grid
https://cssgridgarden.com/

Comment: I tried but breaks https://codepen.io/KGuide/pen/dyZdBay

Comment: The reason it is breaking is because you have forgotten to add a width to the row. Please do that and you will achieve your results.

Comment: i have fixed it in your code pen so it doesn't break, but you should also add media query to control it on different screen sizes.

Comment: Can you share the link of responsive code as the one if checked is still unchanged

Comment: https://codepen.io/KGuide/pen/dyZdBay

Comment: Here is the edited css only

```.item-1 {
    height: 8rem;
    width: 8rem;
  width: 50%;
}

.item-2,
.item-3 {
    margin-top: -4rem;
  width: 40%;
}

.row {
    display: flex;
    gap: 1px;
  width:100%;
    background-color:orange;
}

.item-4 {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 1px;
    width: 26.45%;
}

.item-5 {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 1px;
    margin-left: 4.1rem;
    margin-left: 26.5%;
    width: 26.4%;
}```